# Matching Words lines not to consider in final list but based on index value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Having below lines in a file.

```
god is great
god is excellent
i am excellent
you are not good
I am also bad
world is awesome
```

out of all these lines bottom three lines I need to populate but those lines should not match having word like 'good' and 'awesome'.

Here is code. But it doesn't work as expected.

```
f = open('test2.txt')
lines = [line for line in f.readlines() if line.strip()] 
total_lines=len(lines)

index1=[0,1,2]
all_index=list(range(0,total_lines))

list3 = [i for i in all_index if not i in index1] ## Capturing Index (3,4,5)

words_not_require=['good','awesome']  ## Lines matching these words not required in final list

for j in list3:
    print (''.join(i for i in lines[j] if i not in words_not_require))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
keeplist = []
words_not_require=['good','awesome']
with open('test2.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if not any(word in line for word in words_not_require):
            keeplist.append(line)

print (keeplist)
#Output:
#['god is great', 'god is excellent', 'i am excellent', 'I am also bad']
```

This filters out the lines in your `test2.txt` file that has the words in `words_not_require`

```
keeplist = []
words_not_require=['good','awesome']
with open('test2.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines[3:]: #this gives you lines 4 onwards
        line = line.strip()
        for word in words_not_require:
            line = line.replace(word, '')
        keeplist.append(line)

print (keeplist)
#Output:
#['you are not ', 'I am also bad', 'world is ']
```

Use above code if you just want to replace the words in `words_not_require` in your sliced lines.

Also, use `with` to open your files so that you can skip having to call `f.close()`. `with` will evoke the dunder method `__exit__` to help close the file

Comment: This works: Modified code a bit as per requirement :   for j in list3:
 if not any(word in lines[j] for word in words_not_require):
  list4.append(lines[j])

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to change your last two lines to:

```
for j in list3:
    print(' '.join([word for word in lines[j].split() if word not in words_not_require]))
```

Output:

```
you are not
I am also bad
world is
```